# Making input field visible by the onClick function of the previous input box only works once

Tags: javascript, css, html, asp-classic, vbscript

I've built a form that has 16 input boxes for the user to type in a list of characteristics.

Now, I'm trying to make it so when you click in one of the text fields to type, the next field appears.

It works to make the 2nd box appear and that's all.

I used a for next loop to do this. Below is the code, why won't it work for any consecutive boxes following the 2nd one?

```
1) <input type="text" name="objective1" size="50" onClick="document.getElementById('obj2').style.display='inline';" /><br />

<%

Dim i, b
b = 0

For i = 2 To 16
   b = i+1
   Response.Write("<span id='obj" & i & "' style='display:none'>")
   Response.write(i & ") <input type='text' name='objective" & i & "' size='50' onClick='document.getElementById('obj" & b & "').style.display='inline';' /><br />")
   Response.Write("</span>")
Next

%>
```

I'm developing this at/for work, and we are using IE8, so keep that in mind for function capabilities.

Any input would be great. I think this code makes sense...? It's probably missing a minor piece of code that I'll feel dumb for not realizing lol.

Thank you

** SOLUTION: **

I fixed the problem. It was an issue with the quotations, like @John and @Vlad mentioned.

Except his proposed solution code gave me a syntax error so I had to take a different approach:

```
Response.write(i & ") ") %><input type="text" name="objective<%=i%>" size="50" onClick="document.getElementById('obj<%=b%>').style.display='inline';" /><br /><%
```

I fixed the above line in the For Next loop.

OR as @Martyn0627 submitted:

```
Response.write(i & ") <input type='text' name='objective" & i & "' size='50' onClick=""document.getElementById('obj" & b & "').style.display='inline';"" /><br />")
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) for your issue?

Comment: Is it a problem that the events are not fired for dynamically created divs?

Comment: could we see the html that this code generates?

Comment: @Martyn0627 http://damondicenzo.somee.com/test.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to escape them all, just need to change the one round the onclick. It expects a " but is getting a '. Replace you line of code with this and should have no problems:

```
Response.write(i & ") <input type='text' name='objective" & i & "' size='50' onClick=""document.getElementById('obj" & b & "').style.display='inline';"" /><br />")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have quotes problem in the `onclick` attribute:

```
<input 
type='text' 
name='objective" & i & "' 
size='50' 
onClick='document.getElementById('obj" & b & "').style.display='inline';'  <~~~ HERE
/>
```

Try escaping them (replace single quotes that surround the `onclick` attribute value with double quotes):

```
Response.write(i & ") <input type='text' name='objective" & i & "' size='50' onClick=""document.getElementById('obj" & b & "').style.display='inline';"" /><br />")
```

Comment: This caused a syntax error as well. The single and double quotation marks are crucial in this code so I had to close the ASP tag to do it (see original post for solution)

Answer (score 0):

Use double double quotes in an ASP response.write statement when you want double quotes in your output.

```
Response.write(i & ") <input type=""text"" name=""objective" & i & """ size=""50"" onClick=""document.getElementById('obj" & b & "').style.display='inline';"" /><br />")
```

Edit - My entire page, which I've tested

```
<html>
<head>
<title> New Document </title>

</head>

<body>
1) <input type="text" name="objective1" size="50" onClick="document.getElementById('obj2').style.display='inline';" /><br />

<%

Dim i, b
b = 0

For i = 2 To 16
b = i+1
Response.Write("<span id=""obj" & i & """ style=""display:none"">")
Response.write(i & ") <input type=""text"" name=""objective" & i & """ size=""50"" onClick=""document.getElementById('obj" & b & "').style.display='inline';"" /><br />")
Response.Write("</span>")
Next

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This caused a syntax error. The single and double quotation marks are crucial in this code so I had to close the ASP tag to do it (see original post for solution)

Comment: Strange, it worked for me, although your method is rather better in avoiding quotation the marks hell which is always a problem in this sort of situation